# построение дерева папок и файлов WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

нужно в FolderBrouserDialog выбрать папку и по выбранной папке построить treeview

```
 TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem();
 treeView.Items.Add(root);
private void BuildTree(string path, TreeViewItem node)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                DirectoryInfo[] infoDir = info.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo item in infoDir)
                {
                    TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
                    newItem.Tag = item;
                    newItem.Header = item.Name;
                    newItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkCyan);
                    newItem.Items.Add("*");
                    node.Items.Add(item);
                    progressBar.Value++;
                    BuildTree(item.FullName, newItem);
                }
                FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    TreeViewItem newFile = new TreeViewItem();
                    newFile.Tag = file;
                    newFile.Header = file.Name;
                    newFile.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Chocolate);
                    newFile.Selected += NewFile_Selected;
                    node.Items.Add(newFile);
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

после выполнения нельзя развернуть папки

Comment: ты же проходишь по папкам и файлам и "показываешь" их, правильно? но забыл пройтись по папкам и рекуррентно сделать то же самое

Comment: dgzargo, Спасибо, я уже нашёл свою ошибку

Comment: Не стоит заполнять сразу все вложенные папки. Это может подвесить вашу программу если пользователь выберет. например, корень системного диска. Добавьте команды для Expand и Collapse. которые будут добавлять и очищать коллекции дочерних элементов для папок.

Comment: rdorn, Спасибо за совет, сделаю исправления